# How to implement CCavenue payment integration yii framework version 1

Tags: php, api, yii, ccavenue

I downloaded PHP kit from CCavenue payment integration website. and I followed below steps 
step1--->Login to your dashboard--->Got to resources--->Web integration kit--->PHP kit

step2--->Open PHP kit--->Use non-seamless kit for integration

step3--->Open ccavrequestHandler.php---->mention the access code and working key(use the access code and working key of the same URL)--->check the post action URL i.e.https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction (for the live environment)
         and save the file.
     
step4--->Open ccavresponseHandler file--->Mention the working key---->save the file.

step5--->Mention all the mandatory parameters in dataFrom.htm 
mandatory parameters--->merchant_id,order_id,currency,amount,cancel_url,redirect_url and language(value=en)

step6--->upload all the files on the server

step7--->click on check out
but I don't know where can be uploaded the edited PHP kit files, I am new in yii1 payment gateway integration.

Answer (score 0):

CCAvenue removed the PDF from their website so I removed the official link.

I found the PDF on a different site: http://nilonvalves.com/pdf/

Alternatively, you can download it from https://nofile.io/f/G1hswvhr8rO/CCAVenueWorldIntegrationManual.pdf

Check this manual, it might be what are you looking for. There is something about testing the integration on page 19.

o test your transaction on CCAvenue. Here is the step given by CCAvenue.

This section for all Clients. Now you're ready to test your account by doing Live transactions! Please keep in mind that you cannot test CCAvenue by using American Express or JCB credit card and also any of the Net Banking interfaces. Please use Mastercard, Visa, Diners Club or a Citibank eCard to do a test transaction. Also remember that while placing test orders, always put the words "SUB MERCHANT TEST" in the Instructions text box. After the transaction is successful, please log in to your CCAvenue account using your client ID and Password and cancel the test transaction. Please do not capture the transaction as this would constitute a "cash advance" against one's own cards, which our credit card companies and the payment gateways do not allow on the Internet.